# Need regular expression for atleast 3 alpha numeric values and unlimited numeric values

Tags: javascript, regex

I need  a regular expression which will limit alphanumeric values and unlimited number of numeric values.

1. At least 3 ALPHANUMERIC values
2. Unlimited number of NUMERIC values

I have tried this

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{3,}$/ which will limit characters.
```

And also

```
/^\d+$/ which will check for the numeric values ...
```

But I need to add another condition like unlimited numeric values. I need it in a single regexp.

Comment: So `999` would pass? Somewhat confusing you talk about limiting ALPHANUMERIC but then say "at least 3". Also you say `ALPHANUMERIC` but `a-zA-Z` doesn't allow numbers.

Comment: `Numeric` values are contained in `Alphanumeric` values, is that the right sense of your question?

Comment: Sorry i guess i am not clear with my question ....
my Question is What if we left the 3 character limit on alphanumeric characters and remove the limit for numeric characters only..

Answer (score 2):

```
^(\d*[a-zA-Z]\d*){3,}$
```

Which is three characters a-z surrounded by any amount of numbers, matching strings like "12a34b567c".

To check for alphanumeric (a-z + numbers):

```
^(\d*[a-zA-Z0-9]\d*){3,}$
```

And, this is assuming the characters can be in any order (i.e. *not* starting with 3 alphanumeric characters, followed by numbers only).